# Unable to configure DynamoDB in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, amazon-dynamodb

I'm having difficulty setting up dynamodb with spring. I'm sure there is a problem in my pom file ask my print trace is referring a problem with my datasource and a problem with hibernate which I am not currently using. What I ultimately hope to accomplish is printing out information from my database.  Thanks for any help.

Configure class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableDynamoDBRepositories
public class AWSConfig {

    @Value("${amazon.dynamodb.endpoint}")
    private String amazonDynamoDBEndpoint;

    @Value("${amazon.dynamodb.accesskey}")
    private String amazonAWSAccessKey;

    @Value("${amazon.dynamodb.secretkey}")
    private String amazonAWSSecreyKey;

    @Bean
    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB(){
        AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().withEndpointConfiguration(
                new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:8080", "us-east-2"))
                .build();
        return amazonDynamoDB;
    }

    @Bean
    public AWSCredentials amazonAWSCredentials(){
        return new BasicAWSCredentials(amazonAWSAccessKey, amazonAWSSecreyKey);
    }

}
```

Pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ronpitt305</groupId>
    <artifactId>RestAfrica</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>RestAfrica</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.235</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.derjust/spring-data-dynamodb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.derjust</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Print Trace:

```
2017-12-17 16:58:59.711  INFO 893 --- [           main] com.ronone.RestAfricaApplication         : Starting RestAfricaApplication on Ronalds-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 893 (started by ronaldpitt in /Users/ronaldpitt/Desktop/Java Apps/RestAfrica)
2017-12-17 16:58:59.717  INFO 893 --- [           main] com.ronone.RestAfricaApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-12-17 16:58:59.988  INFO 893 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@429bd883: startup date [Sun Dec 17 16:58:59 EST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-12-17 16:59:02.404  INFO 893 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'httpRequestHandlerAdapter' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=httpRequestHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=httpRequestHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]]
2017-12-17 16:59:03.257  INFO 893 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$68eae0ac] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-12-17 16:59:04.212  INFO 893 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-12-17 16:59:04.244  INFO 893 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2017-12-17 16:59:04.246  INFO 893 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
2017-12-17 16:59:04.533  INFO 893 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-12-17 16:59:04.534  INFO 893 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4567 ms
2017-12-17 16:59:04.821  INFO 893 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-12-17 16:59:04.827  INFO 893 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-17 16:59:04.828  INFO 893 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-17 16:59:04.829  INFO 893 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-17 16:59:04.829  INFO 893 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-17 16:59:04.928  WARN 893 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
2017-12-17 16:59:04.933  INFO 893 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2017-12-17 16:59:04.966  INFO 893 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-12-17 16:59:04.976 ERROR 893 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You have spring-boot-starter-data-jpa as dependency. Hibernate is the default JPA implementation used by Spring and you haven't defined a datasource. If you do not need it remove it.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue? I am struggling with the same one. @alfcope the whole point is to integrate spring data jpa with dynamodb, so removing the dependency is not an option

Answer (score 0):

I just removed

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

From `pom.xml` and the error was resolved.
Make sure you are using `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling` annotations and not JPA's.